# Is it possible specify local .tar(docker image) file path in docker-compose as image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I have the `.tar` file of the docker image and stored it at local file storage. I want to import this image using the `docker-compose.yaml` file. Surely, we can use `docker import` command for this, but I want to do it using `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't reference a tar from `docker-compose` file

It should be path to Dockerfile or git repo address

Docs in : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#context